# Python: Getting the missing datetime intervals

Tags: python

Say that I have this:

```
2/22/2015 3:00
2/22/2015 6:30
2/22/2015 7:00
2/22/2015 7:30
2/22/2015 8:30
2/22/2015 9:30
2/22/2015 11:30
2/22/2015 12:00
```

I want to find the missing 30 minute intervals, so 3:30, 4:00, 4:30, etc.

I have code that generates the missing intervals:

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 22, 3, 30), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 22, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 22, 4, 30),
```

But, the code looks disgusting.

```
available_days = fixed_days.keys()
first_date = min(available_days)
last_date = max(available_days)
no_date = []
for i in range(int((last_date-first_date).days) + 1):
    for z in range(24):
        temp_date = first_date + timedelta(hours=(z),days=i)
        if not temp_date in available_days:
            no_date.append(temp_date)

        temp_date = first_date + timedelta(minutes=(30), hours=(z), days=i)
        if not temp_date in available_days:
            no_date.append(temp_date)

no_date = [d for d in no_date if d<last_date]
```

I'm certain that there's a cleaner way to generate the list I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intervals = int((last_date - first_date).total_seconds()) // (60*30)
no_date = [first_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*60*30)
           for i in range(0, intervals)
           if first_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*60*30) not in fixed_days]
```